# How to multiply (simplify?) two or more Riemann sums?

Tags: summation, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ \sum_{j=i+1}^n\ \sum_{k=1}^j 1$$

I am studying The Algorithm Design Manual, so I have access to the process of simplification from 
http://www.algorist.com/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.1. But I don't understand how each step leads to the next.

The first part of the of the answer from that page is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ \sum_{j=i+1}^n\ j$$

That makes sense. Repeatedly summing "1" from 1 to j is just j. I can reason that.

But the next step is listed as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ \biggl(\sum_{j=1}^nj\ - \sum_{j=1}^ij \biggr)$$

And that's where my reasoning starts to fall apart. What is going on and where should I look to learn more about this? Google searches for "how to multiply Riemann sums" and similar phrases return almost nothing related to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are sums, not Riemann sums, so your searches are probably leading you astray.  Also, you are not multiplying anything, you are *nesting* sums.  You want to manipulate sums.

One random Google hit for "manipulating sums" is

> Bayer, Rob, "[Series Manipulation and Finding Sums](http://zvihrosen.com/S2012-1B/series_tools.pdf)", 06 August, 2010.

It seems like a reasonable place to start.  The step you were stopped by is the third bullet there, "Adding/subtracting missing terms".

Many more examples are on the English Wikipedia page for [Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#General_identities).  The step you were stopped by is the variant immediately following "splitting a sum".

Answer (score 0):

Reasoned my way a little further.

The sum of j from i+1 to n is going to be less than the sum of j from 1 to n. This is because you're starting at i+1 rather than 1, therefore you're not including the sums of j from 1 to i.

So if you sum everything from 1 to n, how much extra did you sum? You need to subtract the sums of j from 1 to i.

That's why:

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^nj = \left (\sum_{j=1}^nj - \sum_{j=1}^ij \right)$$

The rest of the formula uses the fact that a sequence of 1 + 2 + ... + n is equal to n * (n + 1) / 2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF